# How to see HTTP request details that Apache HttpClient sent out

Tags: groovy, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache HttpClient 3.1 to do a simple HTTP Post request where I am passing some JSON over (using basic HTTP auth). Below is the code..

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(cp)
HttpMethod method = new PostMethod(apiUrl)

Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);

 StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(json.toString(), "application/json", "UTF-8")
 method.setRequestEntity(requestEntity)

 def responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method)
```

Is there any way to see (print out) the actual request that was sent? Including the user name and password sent for authentication and the JSON payload?

Reason for asking is I get a cryptic response to this request and I want to send over to the other party all the details I can on my request to help them figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried what it says in the documentation? http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html